# Reading textfile in java using data access object

Tags: java, dao

Last day my professor fed us some lectures that he wasn't able to teach very well.
Although I have a good background in php, but it's kinda different in java, especially the design patterns. He was blabbering about mvc, which is I think different with php's mvc design pattern.

Here is the problem, he posted some codes over the screen which includes 3 files

1. `data-access-object` with a method which does the following (based on my understanding):

   - return an object that has 3 values `accountNumber`, `pinCode`, `balance`
2. `model?` that has `setters` and `getters` on it that gets or sets accountNumber, pinCode and balance
3. and lastly the test which contains the main class, a place where we are to run the code.

I just want to understand or see a better example of this Automated Teller Machine stuffs that uses DAO for accessing a textFile

or maybe can someone just post his/her flowchart, coz i really do not understand it on my own.

Comment: where's your view part of the mvc-- the gui? Or does this question not involve mvc?

Comment: MVC is the same pattern, independtly of language. Different frameworks/language may implement it differently, though.

Comment: Basically the DAO thing is that all access to the file is through a dedicated class. The rest of your app does not know if the data is in a file or a database or anywhere else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> He was
>   blabbering about mvc, which is I think different with php's mvc design
>   pattern.

Design patterns are independent of the language you use.

> data-access-object with a method which does the following (based on my
>   understanding):
>
> 1. return an object that has 3 values accountNumber,
>      pinCode, balance
> 2. model? that has setters and getters on it that gets or sets
>      accountNumber, pinCode and balance
> 3. and lastly the test which contains the main class, a place where we
>      are to run the code.

You should start with your model fist; you just need a bean

```
   public class Account {
        private String accountNumber;
        private int pinCode;
        private long balance;   

        //constructors, setters and getters
    }
```

Then you need to create the DAO class which should look something like this:

```
public interface AccountDAO {
    public Account getAccount(String accountNumber);
    //and other methods
    public List<Account> getAllAccounts(); //this is not suitable for a real bank app
    public void writeAccount(Account account);
    public void deleteAccount(Account account);
    public void updateAccount(Account oldAccount, Account newAccount);
}
```

Having this interface you can implement specific AccountDAO, like FileAccountDAO, XmlAccountDAO, DatabaseAccountDAO.